# What does the number quoted in parentheses mean in man page of some command?

Tags: man

In the Mac OS X Mavericks terminal, inside `frisk` man page, there is:

```
SEE ALSO
       cfdisk(8), sfdisk(8), mkfs(8), parted(8), partprobe(8), kpartx(8)
```

Does it mean see also the eighth `cfdisk` or something else? If so, how can I find all of `cfdisk` from `cfdisk(1)` to `cfdisk(8)`?